# How to set up a loop interval in Swift once a button is pressed?

Tags: swift, loops, nstimer, nstimeinterval

I am trying to set up a looping interval timer for my buttons once they are pressed by the user. For instance, once the 'red' traffic signal is pressed, it will cycle through the remainder of the colours (in order) for a period of 5 seconds each.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var timer : Timer?

    func redButton() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: Selector(("redButton")), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func redButton() {
    }

    var lightRed = true;
    var lightYellow = true;
    var lightGreen = true;

    @IBOutlet weak var stopLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func redButton(_ sender: Any) {
        //TODO: Show text information when 'stop' button is clicked
        stopLabel.text = "Red means stop! Do not proceed forward."
        lightRed = !lightRed
        if lightRed {
            view.backgroundColor = .white
        } else {
            view.backgroundColor = .red
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var waitLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func yellowButton(_ sender: Any) {
        //TODO: Show text information when 'slow' button is clicked
        waitLabel.text = "Yellow means wait, or slow down, as it is about to turn red!"
        lightYellow = !lightYellow
        if lightYellow {
            view.backgroundColor = .white
        } else {
            view.backgroundColor = .yellow
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var goLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func greenButton(_ sender: Any) {
        //TODO: Show text information when 'go' button is clicked
        goLabel.text = "Green means go! Now is the time to proceed forward"
        lightGreen = !lightGreen
        if lightGreen {
            view.backgroundColor = .white
        } else {
            view.backgroundColor = .green
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Outles :-**

```
@IBOutlet weak var viewGreen: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var viewYellow: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var viewRed: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var btnStart: UIButton!

var timer : Timer?
var isRed = true
var isYellow = false
var isGreen = false
```

**Start Button Action :-**

```
@IBAction func btnStart(_ sender: UIButton) {

    self.viewRed.backgroundColor = .red
    self.viewYellow.backgroundColor = .white
    self.viewGreen.backgroundColor = .white

    self.isRed = false
    self.isYellow = true
    self.isGreen = false

    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 5, repeats: true, block: { (timer) in

        if self.isRed {
            self.viewRed.backgroundColor = .red
            self.viewYellow.backgroundColor = .white
            self.viewGreen.backgroundColor = .white

            self.isRed = false
            self.isYellow = true
            self.isGreen = false
        } else if self.isYellow {
            self.viewRed.backgroundColor = .white
            self.viewYellow.backgroundColor = .yellow
            self.viewGreen.backgroundColor = .white

            self.isRed = false
            self.isYellow = false
            self.isGreen = true
        } else if self.isGreen {
            self.viewRed.backgroundColor = .white
            self.viewYellow.backgroundColor = .white
            self.viewGreen.backgroundColor = .green

            self.isRed = true
            self.isYellow = false
            self.isGreen = false
        }
    })
}
```